# Not able to create a profile in Websphere 6.,RAD 7.5 Windows 7

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I work on 2 projects.Both are web applications and i use RAD 7.5 with WAS 6.1 and WAS 6.in one project i worked on WAS 6.1 and it worked properly.For other project, i should use WAS6. Now i am not able 2 create a profile in it.If im trying to use the default profile and start the server im getting the below error.:
[3/13/12 11:19:09:005 GMT] 0000000a TreeBuilder   W   ODCF0002E: Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.util.Util.isNodeAgent(Util.java:106)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder.checkStandAloneServers(TreeBuilder.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder.readCell(TreeBuilder.java:559)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder.buildTargetTree(TreeBuilder.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder.init(TreeBuilder.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder.start(TreeBuilder.java:226)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.ODCService.start(ODCService.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:820)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:649)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:444)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:187)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:570)

Answer (score 0):

What is the environment? I can't make any inferences based on this.

Do you have a separate WAS 6.1 and WAS 6.0 installations or are you playing with the Test environments of RAD.

If you are using the latter, do you have the runtimes installed for both 6.1 and 6.0?

The profile creation seems to be successful as the errors that you face seems to have occurred during the startup of the server.

If you try and go to the profile directory and start instead of relying on default profile, is there any difference?

Post in additional information from your logs (and the corresponding FFDC files so that someone can assist you).

HTH